# Sorting Strings by Character and Length

Tags: sorting, kotlin

In my Android app, I am trying to sort Bus route tags in order 1, 2, 3..etc.

For that I am using this

```
Collections.sort(directions, Comparator { lhs, rhs ->
        var obj1 = lhs.short_names.firstOrNull() ?: ""
        var obj2 = rhs.short_names.firstOrNull() ?: ""

        if (obj1 === obj2) {
            obj1 = lhs.headsigns.firstOrNull() ?: ""
            obj2 = rhs.headsigns.firstOrNull() ?: ""
            if (obj1 === obj2) {
                return@Comparator 0
            }
            obj1.compareTo(obj2)
        } else {
            obj1.compareTo(obj2)
        }
```

The issue I am having is this sorts them, but will run into the issue of
1, 2, 3, 30, 31, 4, 5

How should I change this to get the correct ordering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need just a simple number comparison you can do it like that.

```
directions.sortWith(Comparator { lhs, rhs ->
  val i1 = lhs.toInt()
  val i2 = rhs.toInt()
  when {
    i1 < i2 -> -1
    i1 > i2 -> 1
    else -> 0
  }
})
```

As [hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196460/hotkey) pointed out the code above can be replaced with almost identical implementation that looks much simplier.

```
directions.sortBy { it.toInt() }
```

The general version of this algorithm is called alphanum sorting and described in details [here](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html). I made a Kotlin port of this algorithm, which you can use. It's more complicated than what you need, but it will solve your problem.

```
class AlphanumComparator : Comparator<String> {
  override fun compare(s1: String, s2: String): Int {
    var thisMarker = 0
    var thatMarker = 0
    val s1Length = s1.length
    val s2Length = s2.length

    while (thisMarker < s1Length && thatMarker < s2Length) {
      val thisChunk = getChunk(s1, s1Length, thisMarker)
      thisMarker += thisChunk.length

      val thatChunk = getChunk(s2, s2Length, thatMarker)
      thatMarker += thatChunk.length

      // If both chunks contain numeric characters, sort them numerically.
      var result: Int
      if (isDigit(thisChunk[0]) && isDigit(thatChunk[0])) {
        // Simple chunk comparison by length.
        val thisChunkLength = thisChunk.length
        result = thisChunkLength - thatChunk.length
        // If equal, the first different number counts.
        if (result == 0) {
          for (i in 0..thisChunkLength - 1) {
            result = thisChunk[i] - thatChunk[i]
            if (result != 0) {
              return result
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        result = thisChunk.compareTo(thatChunk)
      }

      if (result != 0) {
        return result
      }
    }

    return s1Length - s2Length
  }

  private fun getChunk(string: String, length: Int, marker: Int): String {
    var current = marker
    val chunk = StringBuilder()
    var c = string[current]
    chunk.append(c)
    current++
    if (isDigit(c)) {
      while (current < length) {
        c = string[current]
        if (!isDigit(c)) {
          break
        }
        chunk.append(c)
        current++
      }
    } else {
      while (current < length) {
        c = string[current]
        if (isDigit(c)) {
          break
        }
        chunk.append(c)
        current++
      }
    }
    return chunk.toString()
  }

  private fun isDigit(ch: Char): Boolean {
    return '0' <= ch && ch <= '9'
  }
}
```

To use this `Comparator` just call

```
directions.sortWith(AlphanumComparator())
```

If you don't need it to be coded in Kotlin you can just take an original Java version on [Dave Koelle's page](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java). And the Kotlin version of the algorithm can be also found on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/MichaelRocks/1b94bb44c7804e999dbf31dac86955ec).

Comment: The first solution with `toInt()` can be rewritten as `a.sortBy { it.toInt() }`.

Comment: @Michael I am slightly confused with implementing it (very new to kotlin) I added the kotlin port
Now to call it I should use
    Collections.sort(directions.sortWith(AlphanumComparator())

or something slightly different?

Comment: @AnthonyTaylor You don't need `Collections.sort()`. Just call `directions.sortWith(AlphanumComparator())`.

Comment: I tried that buy I am getting errors during build

Error:(46, 24) Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:

public fun <T> kotlin.Array<out kotlin.String>.sortWith(comparator: java.util.Comparator<in kotlin.String>): kotlin.Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public fun <T> kotlin.Array<out kotlin.String>.sortWith(comparator: java.util.Comparator<in kotlin.String>, fromIndex: kotlin.Int = ..., toIndex: kotlin.Int = ...): kotlin.Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public fun <T>

Comment: @hotkey Thank you, that's a good point. However, your implementation is not exactly the same as mine as it does additional autoboxing of `Int` But your implementation looks much better. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @AnthonyTaylor What's the type of `directions`?

Comment: @Michael I do believe string off the top of my head **edit**



fun getDirectionsForRoute(routeId: Int) : Observable<List<Direction>>


fun getDirection(routeId: Int, directionId: Int) : Observable<Direction>


So int it seems (Im working off someone else's code, sorry for the lack of knowledge of it.

Comment: Your list is immutable. In this case you can do the following: `val sortedDirections = directions.sortedWith(AlphanumComparator())`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108719/discussion-between-anthony-taylor-and-michael).